# Give us a flag link in the Edit Review queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, flags

I've been reviewing suggested edits lately, and have come across a problem in the queue: we don't have the normal 'flag' link for the post.

I'm not talking about flagging the edit, but the post itself. Often, I will come across a post that, though the edit does *improve* it, still is low quality, and should be flagged as such.

While I want to give the user recognition for trying to improve the post, I also want to let the mods know that it's low quality - and having to go to the question in the normal view isn't very fun for this.

### So, please add a `flag` link below posts in the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: Detours aren't fun? Preposterous! :O

Comment: If it is a low quality post and the suggested edit doesn't do enough then you should consider rejecting the edit.As for flagging: pretty much everyone has a modern browser and a mouse with (at least) three buttons, all you have to do is middle-click on the question title which will open the question in a new tab, you can then flag it then close the tab. Might not be exactly what you wanted but it works.